# JQuery - Getting cycle prev/next to trigger jcarousel prev/next

Tags: jquery, cycle, jcarousellite

I have Cycle running a slideshow, which has prev/next graphics appear when the slideshow is hovered on. The cycle also has a vertical thumbnail pager. I wrapped the pager in a customised version of jCarousellite which puts an .activeSlide class on the active thumbnail and has it's own set of prev/next links.

All in all it's working pretty well and can be seen here:

http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/cycletest/cycle_test.html

However, I have one last hurdle...

When the prev/next graphics on the slideshow are clicked, I want to check if the newly .activeSlide is visible in the carousel and if not, make it so... and I could really do with some help.

To give an example, when you click on my link above you will see there are 8 thumbnails visible in the carousel. Thumbnail 1 is active. If I click on the next graphic on the slideshow, thumbnail 2 becomes active. click again and thumbnail 3 becomes active etc. All well and good until I click for the 8th time and thumbnail 9 becomes active - problem then is that thumbnail 9 is not visible in the carousel - and so at this point I would like some code to activate that would trigger the carousel and make thumbnail 9 visible. (triggering the next link on the carousel would work in this instance)

The solution also needs to deal with a situation like the page loading and the user immediately clicking the prev graphic on the slideshow - which shows the last slide. Triggering the prev link on the carousel would not work here - rather the next link would have to be triggered multiple times to make the active thumbnail visible.

I hope I have been clear - it's actually quite hard to explain what I want to happen but I think it will be pretty obvious when you click on my link above - easier to see than to describe!

I would really like to get this last bit working and would appreciate any help you can give.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

*Maybe*...

```
// When clicking the cycle arrows
$('#slidecontrol a').click(function () {
    var activeSlide = $('div.jcarousellite li.activeSlide');

    // If the "activeSlide" in the jcarousel is not already visible
    if (!activeSlide.is(':visible')) {
        // If there are items ABOVE the active slide that are visible we need to go down
        if (activeSlide.prevAll('li:visible').length) {
            var clicker = $('div.nextlite').find('a');
        }
        // Else we need to go up
        else {
            var clicker = $('div.prevlite').find('a');
        }

        // Keep clicking untill it's visible
        while (!activeSlide.is(':visible')) {
            clicker.click();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks - Looks good but not working unfortunately... http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/cycletest/cycle_test3.html

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. I tried it on your demo page using Chrome's developer tools. For some reason `$('li.activeSlide').is(':visible')` returns true even when it isn't actually visible. It seems jQuery doesn't consider an element `:hidden` just because it's outside it's parent element with `overflow: hidden;`. You could use the exakt same logic but swap the `:visible` bits with a hand made function that checks if an element is outside its parent. _Or_ you could enhance the `:visible` selector to check for that too.

Comment: Thanks powerbuoy  - unfortunately both of those possibilities are probably a bit beyond my current capability.

Comment: It should be pretty easy using `offset()`, `width()` and `height()`. Just calculate how large the containing element (`div.jcarousellite`) is and where it is located, then, based on where the child (`li.activeSlide`) is located you'll know if it's inside or outside its parent. I would recommend expanding the `:visible`-selector though (or creating a method) so as not to clutter the other code.